# Почему featured-блоки на мете и основном сайте различаются?

Tags: поддержка, блок-важных-вопросов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Тема про изменение ширины сайдбара на мете не показывается.
2. В обсуждаемом темы одни и те же, но в разном порядке.

Почему так?

Comment: Я бы добавил, что иконки сайтов еще отличаются. В предстоящих событиях, по-моему, ошибочно показывается иконка основного сайта, а не меты.